# Uploading VI while opening labview file

Tags: labview

I have a very simple yet crucial question:
There is a labview file (VI) that it contains some VIs related to a Tektronix oscilloscope and a motor driver. I have downloaded the drivers and VIs of these hardwares from their company website and added them to the labview file. Now here is the problem; each time that I open that labview file it starts to search for all the related VIs again.How can I solve this problem so there is no need to redo this procedure every time.
thanks

Comment: Saving the VIs after this search should solve this. Make sure you have write access on all files.

Comment: you are right indeed. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the VIs after the first time LabVIEW searches for dependencies should solve this. It's recreating the links, which will be saved with the VIs save, so just make sure you have write access on all files, and you're fine.